# Change version of Maven project without manipulating the POM file

Tags: maven, version, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-versions-plugin

Is it somehow possible to change the version of a Maven project without manipulating the POM file?

Let's say I have a Maven project with version `1.5.0-SNAPSHOT` but I want to build it as `1.5.46`.

The [Versions Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) unfortunately modifies the POM files.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "not modifying the pom file"? You could of course make a defensive copy of the pom, and restore it later (or use a temporary pom file for the build which contains your favourite number).

Comment: I only have one question: Why don't you want to change the pom? In this case it is probably better to explain the root problem instead of asking how to implement a specific solution.

Comment: @RobertScholte We want to create Maven builds with the Git commit count instead of the SNAPSHOT postfix in the version number. The functionality should work both on our Jenkins and locally. We don't want to have to make a commit every time we increment the version therefore the POM files shouldn't be modified.

Answer (score 3):

Since Maven 3.5.0 this is possible using a special predefined property: `${revision}`. Define the property with a default value (e.g. `1.5.0-SNAPSHOT`) and when needed, set it during execution to a specific version (e.g. `1.5.46`).

For example, define the following in your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <name>Foo Module</name>
  <version>${revision}</version>
  ...
  <properties>
    <revision>1.5.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
  </properties>
</project>
```

Build it using the default value:

```
mvn clean install
```

This will produce an artifact identified as `org.example:foo:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT`.

In order to build a specific version, set the `revision` property, for example:

```
mvn clean install -Drevision=1.5.46
```

This will produce an artifact identified as `org.example:foo:1.5.46`.

For further details, see the [Maven CI Friendly Versions](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html) page.

Answer (score 1):

Try to override project version with

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=<version>
```

in your particular case:

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.5.46
```

Comment: Unfortunately this modifies the POM files. I don't want this behavior.

Comment: Do you have your version in pom as a variable?

Comment: Using one version (1.5.45-SNAPSHOT) as another version (1.5.46) is bad. If you do that you cannot be sure which version you are really running. Don't do that. Update the version as shown above (and/or run the release plugin) and commit the modified source to the SCM of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. Make a copy of your pom as `temppom.xml`
2. Replace the version in `temppom.xml`
3. Build with `mvn -f temppom.xml`.
4. Delete `temppom.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Maven supports delivery friendly versions, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5576 .
For more details I would suggest to talk with @khmarbaise

Answer (score 0):

The plugin provides a goal to revert the changes made by it:

```
mvn versions:revert
```